# Pass undetected USB device to QEMU

Tags: qemu, lsusb

I have a CP Plus attendance reader that I want to pass to Windows virtual machine. When I connect the device. I get the following message in dmesg

```
[  372.884498] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  373.832692] usb 1-1: Using ep0 maxpacket: 8
[  373.868850] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error 8
[  373.996653] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  374.196667] usb 1-1: Using ep0 maxpacket: 8
[  374.232507] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error 8
[  374.232847] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[  374.644820] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  374.665128] usb 1-1: Using ep0 maxpacket: 8
[  374.692258] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error 8
[  374.820735] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  374.843037] usb 1-1: Using ep0 maxpacket: 8
[  374.870071] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error 8
[  374.870339] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Because the device is not displayed in lsusb, I redirect it to Qemu. Is there a way to redirect it?

Comment: You can pass it through by the port number. To determine the port number, plug any working device (say, flash disk) into that port, look into `lsusb -t` and notice the port path. These numbers are stable.

Comment: Seems like Linux is having problems even asking the device what kind of device it is. You can pass through an unrecognized device, but it has to work up to the port where Linux is able to communicate with the device (but doesn't know what to communicate because it doesn't know what the device is).